# Firebase gen 2 http function returns 403 for OPTIONS (preflight) request, hence CORS

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I have a firebase function and I have the owner role of the project. Function is written in NodeJS and CORS are enabled. I also got a identity token from cloud console using `gcloud auth print-identity-token`. Requests to the deployed function work fine with Postman.

But when I ran my Angular app, OPTIONS request was blocked by CORS. In the log explorer, there was a warning sayinh the OPTION request weren't authenticated (403).

> The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client

I also checked the request from the browser and it has the `Authorization: Bearer {token}` header.

How is it working on Postman, but not on the browser? Any help?

However, when I added un-authenticated access with

```bash
  gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding [SERVICE_NAME] \
    --member="allUsers" \
    --role="roles/run.invoker"
```

It worked. Any idea why I can't use the authenticated mechanism?

Comment: Since you are using IAP for authorization, CORS support must be enabled: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/customizing#allowing_http_options_requests_cors_preflight